# Can I filter which news appear in the Steam library home?

Tags: steam

In the [newly released Steam Library](https://steamcommunity.com/games/593110/announcements/detail/1666821776739358716), there's a section at the top of the library home labeled "What's new", which shows in a single place all recent news for the games in your library. However, most of the updates I'm seeing are for games I've long stopped playing.

Can I exclude those games from appearing in the "What's new" section?

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, you cannot remove games completely via the interface.

However, an alternative is to right click and select "Show Less From `Game`", which will remove the update and reduce frequency of that game's update appearing on your news feed.

[image: Show Less From Dota 2]

After enough clicks, it should stop appearing completely and thus show news from your more recent games instead.

Comment: *"it should stop appearing completely"*.. well, all I can say - it doesn't. As a proud owner of 1000+ games I am getting swarmed with ALL news. Those "show less/more" are probably meant if you keep news (don't click "remove this update" to clear up), they move news back/forth in the list, nothing else.